# Relative Mean Deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, mean-absolute-deviation

The **Mean Deviation**, also referred to as [Absolute Average Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation), is sometimes preferred to the [Standard Deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) (*Cf.* [Gorard 2004](http://www.leeds.ac.uk/educol/documents/00003759.htm)). For a sample, it can be expressed as:

$MD = \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_i - \overline{x}|$

In order to compare the mean deviations of multiple samples for multiple variables defined with different units, one might want to use a relative version of the Mean Deviation, defined by dividing the Mean Deviation by the absolute value of the mean:

$RMD = \frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_i - \overline{x}|}{|\overline{x}|} = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |x_i - \overline{x}|}{|X|}$

This **Relative Mean Deviation** is mentioned in a few [articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22relative%20mean%20deviation%22&oq=%22relative%20mean%20deviation%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.6103j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8), but has it been thoroughly studied?